# Changing the wildfly.service to newname_wildfly.service

Tags: centos, localhost, wildfly

WildFly noob here. I would like to change the name of the service as said in the title. My question is if I change the name of the file *wildfly.service*, will the whole thing break? What method should I follow to change the name of the service?

wildfly.service file

```
[Unit]
Description=WildFly application server
After=syslog.target network.target
Before=http.service

[Service]
Enviornment=LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=1
EnviornmentFile=-/etc/wildfly/wildfly.conf
User=wildfly
LimitNOFILE?102642
ExecStart=/opt/wildfly/bin/launch.sh $WILDFLY_MODE $WILDFLY_CONFIG $WILDFLY_BIND $WILDFLY_CONSOLE_BIND
StandardOutput=null

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Thank you!

EDIT: It did crash after I changed the file name wildfly.ervice. How do I add a new service with a different name?

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: What I tried first was, renaming the wildfly.service to newname.service,

```
mv wildfly.service newname_wildfly.service
```

knowing it will probably break the whole thing. And it did. After that, I changed it back to wildfly.service and it didn't work. Nor the reload service and starting it up again worked.

So I started the project once again and before creating the *symlink*, I renamed the */etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/**nginx**.service* to ***newname**.service* and then created the *symlink*. I know this maybe isn't the best solution for this but after a lot of research, this was more or less the best option for me.

Hope this helps anyone who ran into the same problem as I did. Cheers!